# Does ServiceStack RedisClient support Sort command?

Tags: redis

my sort command is
"SORT hot_ids by no_keys GET # GET msg:*->msg GET msg:*->count GET msg:*->comments"

it works fine in redis-cli, but it doesn't return data in RedisClient. the result is a byte[][], length of result is correct, but every element of array is null.

the response of redis is 
...
$-1
$-1
...

### c# code is

```
data = redis.Sort("hot_ids ", new SortOptions()
{                    
      GetPattern = "# GET msg:*->msg GET msg:*->count GET msg:*->comments",
      Skip = skip,
      Take = take,
      SortPattern = "not-key"
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redis Sort is used in `IRedisClient.GetSortedItemsFromList`, e.g. from [RedisClientListTests.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Redis.Tests/RedisClientListTests.cs#L405):

```
[Test]
public void Can_AddRangeToList_and_GetSortedItems()
{
    Redis.PrependRangeToList(ListId, storeMembers);

    var members = Redis.GetSortedItemsFromList(ListId, 
      new SortOptions { SortAlpha = true, SortDesc = true, Skip = 1, Take = 2 });

    AssertAreEqual(members, 
      storeMembers.OrderByDescending(s => s).Skip(1).Take(2).ToList());
}
```

You can use the [MONITOR](http://redis.io/commands/monitor) command in redis-cli to help diagnose and see what requests the ServiceStack Redis client is sending to redis-server.

Comment: I get command from MONITOR, it's:   

  `  "SORT" "qjr:top" "BY" "not-key" "LIMIT" "0" "20" "GET" "# GET   qjr:msg:*->a GET qjr:msg:*->l GET qjr:msg:*->c"  `

it should be 

  ` "SORT" "qjr:top" "BY" "not-key" "LIMIT" "0" "20" "GET" "#" "GET" "qjr:msg:*->a" "GET" "qjr:msg:*->l" "GET" "qjr:msg:*->c"  `

redisClient doesn't support muti-get  very well.